# Can we create a local database for my application without making it dependent of the OS in which it is installed?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I mean, for example, installing a database using a webserver then deploy the database with my application without more configuration, just a portable database, is it possible? Currently my mongo database is installed and dependent of my computer system, I would make it portable, it is possible to build a database upon my webserver, hence make it portable? 
Any hint would be great,
thanks

Comment: Do you actually mean something like `var uri = process.env['DATABASE_URI']` as opposed to hardcoding `var uri = 'mongodb://localhost:27017'`? The common process for this is environment variables and configuration files. That way the database your application connects to is decoupled from the actual code.

Comment: Your hint is very interesting, thanks, I would mean decoupled my database from my localhost and running it independently of my host system, like any other package and just push it with my app